# Can I install a font on the client side in a Java 1.4 web app?

Tags: java, fonts, client, installation

I need to use a custom barcode font in a sticker I create in PDF. Is there a way to install it to a users system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to. Install it on the server side where the PDF is being created. Client will download the PDF displaying correctly bar codes.

Comment: Another problem came up, but as for this, it works, thank you :)

Comment: Post another question. We'll help you. Svako dobro.

Comment: Followup on the topic: Pdfbox in an applet, barcode font problem. I hvala, također :)

Answer (score 0):

Generate the PDF with the font embedded. Then it can display anywhere without downloading anything other than the PDF itself.